Sending Multiple SignalR message from single Azure Isolated Function
I have a function app that is used to manage refreshing data on a widget dashboard that was originally built on the in-process model. We have a single endpoint RefreshDashboard that sends multiple SignalR messages to update users on the status of the refresh while also blocking other users from attempting multiple concurrent refreshes. The existing endpoint looks something like this
[FunctionName("RefreshProjectData")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RefreshProjectDataAsync(
    [HttpTrigger( AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Dashboard/RefreshProjectData")] 
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    [SignalR(HubName = SignalRHubs.ProjectDashboard)] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> notifications
)
{
    try
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        await notifications.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
        {
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new object[] { "Refresh Started by user {user}" }
        });
        BeginDataCollection();
        await notifications.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
        {
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new object[] { $"Data collection finished at {DateTime.Now}" }
        });
        RebuildWidgetStatistics();
        await notifications.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
        {
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new object[] { $"Refresh Finished at {DateTime.Now}" }
        });
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        await notifications.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
        {
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new object[] { $"Refresh failed. Please try again at {DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)}" }
        });
    }
}

However, isolated functions no longer use the SignalRAttribte  and instead use SignalROutputAttribute and makes sending multiple messages less obvious. Currently, I have created a separate HttpTrigger methods that my RefreshData method calls to send the SignalR messages. I have also defined an SignalRTrigger as well to check if things are working for a quick smoke test. My SignalR connection is set under AzureSignalRConnectionString in local.settings.json
Parts of this were influenced by this SignalR Sample from the ASP.NET team
[Function("RefreshDataMock")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RefreshDataMock([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
    var body = new StringContent("SignalR Message");
    await new HttpClient().PostAsync($"http://{req.Url.Authority}/api/SignalRTest", body);
    return response;
}
[Function("SignalRTest")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = Hub)]
public SignalRMessageAction SignalRTest([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    var content = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
    return new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage")
    {
        GroupName = "ProjectDashboard",
        Arguments = new[] { content }// read the signalR message from the HTtp body ,
    };

}
[Function(nameof(ProcessSignalRMessage))]
public static void ProcessSignalRMessage(
    [SignalRTrigger("ProjectDashboard", "messages", "newMessage", "content")]
    SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext, string content, FunctionContext functionContext)
{
    var logger = functionContext.GetLogger(nameof(ProcessSignalRMessage));
    logger.LogInformation("Connection {connectionId} sent a message. Message content: {content}", invocationContext.ConnectionId, content);
}

At first glance, this looks like it should work. When I use Postman to invoke RefreshDataMock the call to SignalRTest does not throw an error, but the receiving trigger ProcessSignalRMessage is never executed and the Azure Portal does not show any new messages or connections.
Is my approach incorrect and there is a different way I should be doing this or am I just potentially missing a configuration step somewhere?

It's a creative solution, but doing an HTTP call from your own API back to itself probably isn't the right approach. So instead of using the [SignalRAttribute] could you instead consider injecting the SignalR client as a constructor parameter, so you can use it just as a normal method call? Then you could send multiple SignalR messages in the same HttpTrigger. I can show you an example if you're happy with that approach.

The below method worked for me in .Net 8 Isolated Azure function
[SignalROutput] binding is used along with Function return type as List<SignalRMessageAction>
    [Function("Broadcast")]
    [SignalROutput(ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString", HubName = HubName)]
    public List<SignalRMessageAction> Broadcast(
    [SignalRTrigger(HubName, "messages", "broadcast", "message")] SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext, string message)
    {
        var multipleMessageoutput = new List<SignalRMessageAction>
        {
            new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage") // Message targeted for all users
            {
                Arguments = ["Message targeted for all audiance"]
            },
            new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage") // Message targeted for  group
            {
                Arguments = ["Message targeted for a group"],
                GroupName = "console"
            }
        };
        return multipleMessageoutput;
    }

